# mysql duplicate check on 2 columns together

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unique-constraint

### Table

```
|ID|owner|page|value|
|1 |0001 |home|demo |
|2 |0003 |home|demo |
|3 |0001 |home|demo |
```

what  i want is to prevent owner to set 2 values for same page.

so my current approch was

```
|ID|owner|page|value|unique_check
|1 |0001 |home|demo |0001_home
|2 |0003 |home|demo |0003_home
unique_check is (unique key).
```

and  now when ever im inserting into this table on php side i set unique_check = owner_page
and since unique_check is a unique column mysql give an error and do not insert if that owner already did set value for this page.

but my question is , is there a way to do this on mysql only without php help or without extra 'unique_check' column ?
(set unique to 2 columns together)

if there is no way to set unique-constrain to 2 columns, can i set unique_check default value = owner_page , so i wouldnt worry about doing that from php ?

Comment: why don't you use composite key constraint .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, add `UNIQUE` constraint,

```
ALTER TABLE tableNAME ADD CONSTRAINT tb_UQ UNIQUE (owner, page)
```

Comment: does this match when both col1,col2 exist or when either one of them ?

Comment: match when both exist. consider this record for `Owner, Page`, `1, home`, `2, home`, `2, index`. They are valid.

Comment: But not `Owner, Page`, `1, home`, `1, home`, `2, index`